# Disable all power options from the Start menu

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I'm working on an application that resembles a kiosk. After the application starts, it creates a new desktop and using a key combo I can move back and forth between desktops.

This newly created desktop needs to have limited capabilities. In order to do this, I've used `RegCreateKeyEx` and `RegSetValueEx` functions to create or modify the registry entries for *Task Manager*, *Change Password*, *Lock*, *Shut Down*, *User Switching* and *Log Off*. I've disabled Log Off from two locations, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, using the code below:

```
bool RegistryUtilities::changeSingleFeature(HKEY regKey, LPCWSTR subKey, DWORD value, LPCWSTR valueName)
{
    bool resultOk = false;
    HKEY hkey;
    DWORD dwDisposition;
    if (RegCreateKeyEx(regKey, subKey, 0, NULL, 0, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &hkey, &dwDisposition) == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        if (RegSetValueEx(hkey, valueName, 0, REG_DWORD, (PBYTE)&value, sizeof(DWORD)) == ERROR_SUCCESS){
            resultOk = true;
        }
        RegCloseKey(hkey);
    }
    return resultOk;
}

bool RegistryUtilities::changeAllFeatures(DWORD value)
{
    bool resultOk = true;

    /// Task Manager
    HKEY regKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    LPCWSTR subKey = L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System";
    LPCWSTR valueName = L"DisableTaskMgr";
    if (changeSingleFeature(regKey, subKey, value, valueName) == false)
        resultOk = false;

    /// Change Password
    valueName = L"DisableChangePassword";
    if (changeSingleFeature(regKey, subKey, value, valueName) == false)
        resultOk = false;

    /// Lock
    valueName = L"DisableLockWorkstation";
    if (changeSingleFeature(regKey, subKey, value, valueName) == false)
        resultOk = false;

    /// Log Off
    subKey = L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer";
    valueName = L"NoLogOff";
    if (changeSingleFeature(regKey, subKey, value, valueName) == false)
        resultOk = false;

    /// Shut Down
    valueName = L"NoClose";
    if (changeSingleFeature(regKey, subKey, value, valueName) == false)
        resultOk = false;

    /// User Switching
    regKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    subKey = L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System";
    valueName = L"HideFastUserSwitching";
    if (changeSingleFeature(regKey, subKey, value, valueName) == false)
        resultOk = false;

    return resultOk;
}
```

Even all these options are disabled the "Log Off" option on the start menu is still visible and working. In the *CTRL+ALT+DEL* menu, everything is disabled, only a Cancel option is present, as I intended.

As a curiosity, in `changeAllFeatures` function I've changed the order in which `changeSingleFeature` is called, beginning with the calls for the *Log Off* option and I was not surprised to see that in the *CTRL+ALT+DEL* menu everything was still disabled, but in the Start menu the *Log Off* was disabled, but every other option (*Shut Down, Switch User, Lock* etc.) was enabled and working.

Is it possible to disable all this options, including the Log Off?

Comment: Please don't mark C++ code as runnable Javascript. I fixed this.

Comment: If you want a kiosk, use your own shell

Comment: I think you'd have better luck asking this question on SuperUser. It's probably better solved with Windows configuration rather than code.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried numerous ways to do this and I think it's impossible. I've tried winapi code (as seen in the post), I've tried direct registry editing (using regedit) and  through a group policy and nothing seems to work. I've come to the conclusion (it's my guess, I'm not sure) that this is a safety feature on Windows because if you are able to remove all power options and log in/log off you won't be able to do a normal shut down, and in the case of a power failure for example, you won't be able to acces your pc, past the log in desktop, since that will be disabled.